# Icon link without text eslint error

Tags: accessibility, eslint

I have a React project that shows a bunch of social media links that are just icons to their respective sites.  I use icomoon fonts and whatnot to provide the icon-* classes to show the social media icons.

The error I get, understandably, is:

`Anchors must have content and the content must be accessible by a screen reader`

What should I do in this scenario where I don't want anything but the icon and no text?  I'm not sure how to properly do this so everyone's happy.

*Edit*

I didn't think code was necessary since it doesn't pertain to anything really.

Here's the mapping that spits out the links.  As you can see, no text.  Just font-icons for whatever social media site is being linked to:

```
{this.props.siteInfo.social.map(function(item, i){
    return <a key={i} className={`nav_item icon-${item.social_media_type}-square`} href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
})}
```

Which results in:

`<a key="0" class="nav_item icon-facebook-square" href="facebook.com/someprofile" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>`

Comment: post your code :)

Comment: I got around the issue by simply adding null i.e. <a ..... >{null}</a> Can anyone suggest any problems that might arise from this?

Comment: Yes: https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-refs.html

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and I solved it by just adding one white space

`<a><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>`

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer here:

https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/

It seems you should add a some text that you can hide via CSS, although not with `display:none;` or anything of that sort.  Screen readers will ignore that.

I'm not sure if this is the most current way to do things, but it does work and achieves accessibility and eslint is happy.

Comment: Alternatively https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, solved it like this with React (same suggestion as @danielInixon

```
 const IconLink = props => {
   const { name } = props;
   return <a aria-label={name} href="https://github.com/johnb8005/svg">
     <i className={`fa fa-${name}`} aria-hidden="true"/>
   </a>;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the CSS workaround:

Add some Text.
Add some CSS:

- `text-indent: 100%;`
- `white-space: nowrap;`
- `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

That means you wrote you text in side the 'i' tag
as in
     your text
instead

```
<a><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> your text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues for my header design system and found a solution here:

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20208

To clarify, here's the difference:

**Before:**

*const ExternalButton = styled( ({ ...props}) => <a {...props} />)``*

**After:**

const ExternalButton = styled( ({ children, ...props}) => <a {...props}{children} </ a>)

*Please note that a space had to be included in the </ a>  for it to render on the post. Please remove it for the functional answer*